# Run all Lua files in a directory

Tags: lua

Lets say I have the file `main.lua`, and in a sub-directory I have a series of Lua scripts which I would like to run. Is there a way to run all the scripts in the subdirectory in plain vanilla Lua - that is, without needing to load any external modules or packages? The `require` and `dofile` work on only single files as far as I can tell, I would like to be able to do something like `require "subdir/*"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have access to os.execute? Can you maintain a list of the modules you want to load?

If you have a full Lua interpreter it is pretty easy to do what you want. (Here's an example for Windows)

```
 local f = io.popen("dir /b") for mod in f:lines() do require(mod) end
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to run all the scripts in the subdirectory in plain vanilla Lua - that is, without needing to load any external modules or packages?

No. Lua is designed to be an embedded language. As such, "vanilla Lua" is very small. It has few filesystem-based features; iterating through a directory and pattern-matching files is not possible.

If you are serious about using Lua as a shell-scripting language, then you need to get used to using Lua modules to get things done.

Comment: I suspected this was the case. I was hoping that there would be some way to get require to not stop at the first pattern match, and keep running through all the matches in the path. It seems like it has all the functionality necessary to do such a task without external modules, but I suspected that there was no built-in way to do it. :-/